# inserting a .on(load) timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to load some images dynamically via .on('load') - via the following script:

```html
.on('load', function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#rateholder").append(img);
        }
    });
```

Sometimes, however, the attempt fails for some reason or other.  I'd like to put a timeout on it so if the image hasn't loaded within say...10 seconds...it runs a different function.

How would I append a timeout to this?

Comment: What object does that `.on()` belong to? Something that holds multiple images, or...? Do you want separate timeouts, one per image?

Comment: Set a timeout that triggers the error event and remove the timeout inside the onload. This assumes it is only one element.

Comment: Forgot to add that - sorry ;)

var img = $("<img id='rateme' style='max-width:100%; max-height:500px;' />").attr('src', ''+myimg)

Comment: It's attached to a placeholder - that loads a single image at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that checks your image exists every 10 seconds.

Then do what you need if it doesn't.

```
var oneSecond = 1000;    
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if ($('#the-image').length) {
      console.log("Exists!");
      clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
   else{
        console.log('Does not Exist');  
        clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
}, oneSecond*10);
```